# How to emulate this jQuery behaviour with reactJS: add/ remove className from different divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I wanted to learn reactJS, I know jQuery, I want to know how to achieve the below jQuery add class remove class function in reactJS.

There is no proper tutorial for this anywhere for the beginner like me, I here and there saw someone achieved this using an npm package "classNames" but cant understand how to use that. So please someone post a simple and effective code to achieve this so I can learn.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sexSelect').click(function(event){
        $('.sexSelect').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

```css
.sexSelect.active { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Sex - Click Anyone</h1>
<span class="sexSelect active">MALE  &nbsp;&nbsp; </span>
<span class="sexSelect">FEMALE</span>
```

Comment: do you have any knowledge about react already? what have you tried so far? how is your component structured? this is a jquery example, what have you done in react?

Comment: Yes @rebecca i create a components for the designs that provided to me, then i set a static route for the components and forward that to development team. now i wanted to learn react by practical examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Create a boolean that represents if the class is active or inactive.
- Write the className of your node like this:
  `className={isMyClass ? 'activeName' : 'inactiveName' }`
- In the `onClick` prop of your button attach the function that updates the boolean.

For example, you can achieve something like this with react hooks:

```
const ToggleClassExample = () => {
    const [isMyClass, setIsMyClass] = useState(true);

    return (
        <div>
            <div className={isMyClass ? 'activeName' : 'inactiveName' }>Hello world</div>
            <button onClick={() => setIsMyClass(!isMyClass)}>Toogle class</button>
        </div>;
    );
};
```

Comment: This will create infinite re-renders, since your onclick is wrapped incorrectly. It should be `onClick={() => setIsMyClass(!isMyClass)}`, or `onClick={handleOnClick}`, where `handleOnClick` will call `setIsMyClass(!isMyClass)`

Comment: Hi @Kobe can you please demonstrate how can i use the above mentioned solution to emulate like the jquery function i posted?. your help means lot to me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use react hooks' `useState` to store which item was last clicked, and render an active class using a conditional ternary:

```js
const { useState } = React;

const App = () => {

  const [selected, setSelected] = useState('male')

  return (
    <div className='us-none'>
      <h1>Sex - Click Anyone</h1>
      <span 
        onClick={() => setSelected('male')}
        className={'sexSelect' + (selected === 'male' ? " active" : '')}
      >MALE</span>
      &nbsp;|&nbsp;
      <span 
        onClick={() => setSelected('female')}
        className={'sexSelect' + (selected === 'female' ? " active" : '')}
      >FEMALE</span>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
.sexSelect.active {
  color: red;
}

.sexSelect {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.us-none {
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: this solution is what i needed @kobe. Appreciate your time to make me learn a new thing in react, Thanks.

Comment: What if i wanted to make a male as active default, like a radio button.Kindly Reply @kobe.

Comment: You would pass male as the default value, like this: `useState('male')`